# Woocommerce Order Notes Didn’t Understand Line Break

Tags: html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

My website’s woocommerce plugin has a problem. The ‘Order Note’ didn’t understand line break!

For example, if I write this text in ‘Order Note’ section:

1

2

3

It will show like this:

123

And I have to use `<br />` between each line!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What should I explain that I did not explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you check how is this note stored in the database. WooComerce order notes are stored in the wp_comments table. Check the stored message using phpmyadmin or other database tool.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_comments`
WHERE `comment_post_ID` = {order_id}
ORDER BY `comment_ID` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

There are 2 options when you add the note with content:

```
1
2
3
```

#1 The content of the order note in the database will be the same

```
1
2
3
```

This means something is messing up your output.

Order notes are printed using this line:

```
<?php echo  wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $note->content ) ) ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
```

This line will replace newlines with `<br>` automatically. So if your comment look ok in the database, look for a problem with the output, check all these functions, hooks they trigger...

#2 The content in the wp_comments will look like

```
1 2 3
```

or

```
123
```

This means something is messing up your note **before**  storing in the database.
Order note is stored using function `$order->add_order_note()`. Inside this function, there is a filter `woocommerce_new_order_note_data` that could be doing something with the order note text before saving. Also, when adding order notes manually on the order page, the text is cleaned up using this line

```
$note      = wp_kses_post( trim( wp_unslash( $_POST['note'] ) ) );
```

I would say the option #2 is more likely, something is messing up the note before the storing but you have to check that.

Comment: Hey, did you fix the problem? And what was the issue in the end?